# Cooperating with the authorities on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, leniencies, police-authorities

To what extent, if any, must a Jew go through in order to cooperate with authorities, who are **not** seeking to persecute Jews, in ways that violate Shabbat? May he violate rabbinic ordinances, or actual torah law in an indirect or unnatural way (shinuey)? Or, is there no leeway whatsoever no matter what the potential consequence of obstruction is (short of death)?

Comment: This question is way to vague for an answer. What are the circumstances? Are the authorities evacuating a burning building? Are they searching for a criminal? Are they just persecuting Jews?

Comment: @Daniel better?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26137/472

Comment: @nikmasi, I still think this is not specific enough of a question. The context is important. Do you think the answer to this question would be the same in every situation?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13181/759

Comment: @Daniel I think a good answer would outline principles that could cover various situations.

Comment: @Daniel I would not be surprised if the answer is "cooperate with the police first; ask questions later," in which case a general question like this one makes sense.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I'd be surprised if that were the answer. If a policeman comes to my home and says "we'd like you to ride down to the station to help us investigate a string of misdemeanors, can you come along now please?", I suspect the _p'sak_ would be "don't go".

Comment: @msh210, you're probably right, but I maintain that it's valid to ask, generally, whether that's true and how to draw the line.

Comment: I think you should behave as if they were not authorities - i.e. does the situation merit violating a Rabbinic or Torah prohibition based on the situation alone. The fact that they are authorities, and might even arrest you should change nothing.

Comment: @Ariel, in practice, the fact that authorities are making a request *could* feed into the analysis of whether the situation merits setting aside various kinds of prohibitions. One could conceive of a respnsum providing a practical guideline along the lines of "if police ask for your help in a criminal investigation, comply first and analyze after." or "If police tell you to move, move first and analyze after."